# Problem with IF statement for DOM animation & effects with JQuery' assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a simple slideshow, it's part of my 'DOM animation & effects with JQuery' assignment, focusing on JavaScript, HTML, CSS and jQuery.

The assignment is simple: Create a slideshow with 2 buttons (Prev & Next). When I click on the corresponding button it should take me to the next slide or the previous slide.

```js
var $one = $(".one")
var $two = $(".two");
var $three = $(".three");
var $four = $(".four");
var $five = $(".five");
var $six = $(".six");
var $seven = $(".seven");

$two.hide();
$three.hide();
$four.hide();
$five.hide();
$six.hide();
$seven.hide();
$one.slideDown();

var $prev = $("prev");
var $next = $("next");


$next.on("click", function() {
  if ($one.slideDown()) {
    $one.hide();
    $two.slideDown();
  } else {
    $one.slideDown();
  }
});

$prev.on("submit", function() {
  if ($one.slideDown()) {
    $one.hide();
    $six.slideDown();
  } else {
    $one.slideDown();
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  border: 6px rgb(245, 166, 166) solid;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/mushroom.png" width="500" alt="Mushrooms" class="one">
<img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/berries.png" width="500" alt="Berries" class="two">
<img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/broccoli.png" width="500" alt="Broccoli" class="three">
<img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/brussels-sprouts.png" width="400" alt="Sprouts" class="four">
<img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/chocolates.png" width="500" alt="Chocolates" class="five">
<img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/fruits.png" width="500" alt="Fruits" class="six">
<img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/cake.png" width="500" alt="Cake" class="seven">
<button type="submit">⬅︎ Prev︎</button>
<button type="click">Next ➡</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've spent much time trying to figure out the best way to do this and then came up with the solution above, however the IF statement isn't working too well.

I'm not looking for the solution or straight up answer - just guidance, of where the problem is/hints on how to tackle it (also a link to a video that could give me a similar problem/walkthrough/tutorial would be greatly appreciated!).

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: `if ($one.slideDown())` is not the proper way to check if the element is visible or not. Instead, try `if ($one.is(":visible"))`

Comment: I'm conflicted to help you here as its for an assignment, and I don't want to give you code to regurgitate. However @TylerRoper has solved the immediate issue with the `if` statement. Going a step further I'd suggest you look in to the DRY principle, and how you can genericise this logic using a single function for every image without needing an `if` statement at all. Without it you're going to have very verbose, difficult to maintain logic.

Comment: Thanks Tyler and Rory. If anyone else could suggest an other principles or videos (tutorials) expanding on the above that would be a lot of help. I'm here to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks much better like this. There are a few edge cases but you should be able to handle them now.

What I did: 
- Gave a slide class to the slider
- I add is-active class to the active slider
- Remove the is-active when button is clicked

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Project: Interactive slideshow</title>
            <style>
            img {
                border: 6px rgb(245, 166, 166) solid;
            }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>

        <br>
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/mushroom.png" width="500" alt="Mushrooms" class="slide" >
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/berries.png" width="500" alt="Berries" class="slide" >
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/broccoli.png" width="500" alt="Broccoli" class="slide" >
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/brussels-sprouts.png" width="400" alt="Sprouts" class="slide" >
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/chocolates.png" width="500" alt="Chocolates" class="slide" >
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/fruits.png" width="500" alt="Fruits" class="slide" >
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/cake.png" width="500" alt="Cake" class="slide" >
        <button class="prev">⬅︎ Prev︎</button>
        <button class="next">Next ➡</button>

    <script>
        var slide = $(".slide")

        slide.hide();
        slide.first().show().addClass('is-active');
        // slide.first().slideDown();

        //variables
        var prev = $(".prev");
        var next = $(".next");

        //Next button action
        next.on("click", function() {
            slide.hide();
            $('.is-active').removeClass('is-active').next().addClass('is-active').show();

        });

        //Prev button action
        prev.on("click", function() {
            slide.hide();
            $('.is-active').removeClass('is-active').prev().addClass('is-active').show();

        });
    </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

**NOTE:** Please try avoiding classes like one, two, three so on. Because if there are like 1000 images you will not add 1000 lines of code because that will become a mess.

Comment: Muhammed - Are you able to go into more detail about: 'Gave a slide class to the slider - I add is-active class to the active slider - Remove the is-active when button is clicked' ? 1. Why did you add the class and remove it? What does it do (tell) the system to do? I'm just trying to understand this as we have yet to cover in more detail adding/removing classes. More so in the below part of the code:

```
$('.is-active').removeClass('is-active').next().addClass('is-active').show();

````

Comment: Yes, so 'is-active' class is added to the active slide (that is visible at the moment). So initially the 'is-active' class will be on the first image. When a button click is detected lets say on next button. The code finds the item that has this class. ```$('.is-active')``` by this piece of code. Then removes this class from this item because this item is no more active hence ```$('.is-active').removeClass('is-active')```. Now it finds the next element because next button was clicked hence ```$('.is-active').removeClass('is-active').next()```. See next comment.

Comment: Now it adds the active class to that next element hence ```$('.is-active').removeClass('is-active').next().addClass('is-active')```. Then simply shows that element hence ```$('.is-active').removeClass('is-active').next().addClass('is-active').show()```. Then previous click is similar just replacing prev() with next(). I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your response/break down. I'm using the code, but I seem to be getting all the slides displayed, also the next/prev buttons have no response. Is the code a solution or is there more work to be done on my side, just a little confused?

Comment: 'There are a few edge cases but you should be able to handle them now.' - what are edge cases??

Comment: Edge case 1: When you are on first image and click the back button then there is no previous element.

Comment: Edge case 2: When you are on the last image and click next button. But there is no next element.